# AS3 adding EventListener to array of movieClips but getting error #2007 :Parameter listener must be non-null

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an event listener to ALL of my buttons in the buttons array.  I can make them buttons within the loop but when I try and add the event listener is give me this error:

`TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter listener must be non-null.
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/addEventListener()
    at Main()`

I can add this event to another array but just not this one. Ive placed these buttons on the stage and gave them instance names which I'm referring to in my as file.  I am learning AS3 in school so this is probably a very obvious problem but Im not qualified to debug my code yet :S Thanks for all your help.

```
//array of buttons and making them buttons
var buttons:Array = [armButton, lobeButton, beakButton, crotchButton, earButton, hairButton, legButton, shoulderButton, spineButton, tailButton, tearButton, eyeButton];

for(var b:int = 0; b<buttons.length; b++){
    buttons[b].buttonMode = true;
    buttons[b].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickMe);
}

function clickMe(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("hello");
}
```

Comment: If your class file isn't huge, post the whole thing. Is this AS file your document class?

Comment: before your for loop and the `clickMe` function, do a simple `trace(armButton)` and see what happens.

Comment: Now that you're learning AS3, you should learn debugging first, the most important concept in coding. To find out what's happening, paste the following in your loop, before those 2 lines: `trace('b:',b); trace('button:',buttons[b]);`

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the "clickMe" function both in definition and parameters-section, make sure that exactly the same characters are used (a character can sometimes be mistaken for the character from another code table). The error occurs because "clickMe" expression is null at the moment when the loop is being executed.

```
var buttons:Array = [armButton, lobeButton, beakButton, crotchButton, earButton, hairButton, legButton, shoulderButton, spineButton, tailButton, tearButton, eyeButton];

for(var b:int = 0; b<buttons.length; b++){
    buttons[b].buttonMode = true;
    // what is the output of the following expression?
    trace(clickMe) // should be "function Function() {}"
    buttons[b].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickMe);
}

function clickMe(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your addEventListener line clickMe is null.

I suspect that we aren't seeing all the code here. Is that code together in the same file ? Or did you cut/paste just parts you thought were important ?